# split string whenever there are 5 spaces

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this

```
ADBL 489 ( 156 ) (  33 )     AHPC 434 ( 243 ) (  4 )     AIC 715 ( 200 ) (  50 )
```

I want to split this into three strings:

- `ADBL 489 ( 156 ) (  33 )`
- `AHPC 434 ( 243 ) (  4 )`
- `AIC 715 ( 200 ) (  50 )`

Between them are 5 spaces. How can I achieve this using regular expressions in PHP. I tried this, but its not working:

```
$splited_string = preg_split('/\s\s\s\s\s/', $string);
```

Comment: try explode with 5 blanks like '_____'

Comment: Is it a requirement to do this with regular expressions or is it just the only way you could imagine? ;) Because there are better ways, as some of the answers and comments show.

Comment: in your example, shouldn't AIC be there too?

Comment: On another note...what do you mean by "is not working"? Your code works exactly as it should for me. See [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qhTcIQ).

Comment: @TillHelge Agree with you, it works :)

Comment: yes @Martijn AIC too, and everthing that follows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[php.net /  explode](https://www.php.net/explode)

> Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string
> formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

```
$array = explode("     ", $string);
```

---

If you want it back to the string again, you can use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

> Returns a string containing a string representation of all the array elements in the same order, with the glue string between each element.

```
$string = implode(" and ", $array);
```

---

If you want the 5(or more) spaces replaced with something else:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\s{5,}/", " and ", $string); // {5} will make exact 5
```

You should be carefull with regexes. It's a powerfull tool, but you should only equip the big guns when the lightweight options are none. In the examples above, this would be faster because arrays for stringmanipulation rarely pay off.

Comment: Then you're using this wrong, because in my test this works. Not a lot to go wrong on either...

Comment: @MilanMaharjan Please go back to your question and check if you really explained correctly what you want to achieve. Sounds a little bit like your expectation and your explanation might be out of sync.

Comment: seems like there was &nbsp; in the string, which was just displayed as a space when i echoed it. so there exactly weren't 5 spaces, there was 4 spaces and one &nbsp; . I put it in the regex and now its working. Any way I am marking your answer as correct, though everybody else were right too. thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

something like this:

```
$pizza="ADBL 489 ( 156 ) (  33 )     AHPC 434 ( 243 ) (  4 )     AIC 715 ( 200 ) (  50 )";
$parts=explode("     ", $pizza);
echo $parts[0]; // ADBL 489 ( 156 ) (  33 )
echo $parts[1]; // AHPC 434 ( 243 ) (  4 )
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work.

```
$str = 'ADBL 489 ( 156 ) (  33 )     AHPC 434 ( 243 ) (  4 )     AIC 715 ( 200 ) (  50 )';
$strings = explode('     ', $str);
print_r($strings);
```